# how to correct the error in unknown attribute in rails?

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails

i'm using has_many and belongs_to. i'm trying to insert the value of two models in one view page.but it shows error and here is my code

my controller page:

```
class DepositinterestsetupsController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @depositinterestsetup = Depositinterestsetup.new
    @depositinterestrate = @depositinterestsetup.depositinterestrates.build
  end
end

def create
  @depositinterestsetup = Depositinterestsetup.new(params[:depositinterestsetup]) 
  if @depositinterestsetup.save 
    flash[:success] = "Welcome!"
    redirect_to depositinterestsetups_path          
  else
    flash[:alert] = "Interest not added"
    render 'new'
  end    
end
```

my model page

```
class Depositinterestsetup < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many:depositinterestrates
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :depositinterestrates,:allow_destroy => true
  attr_accessible :effective_from, :effective_to, :depositinterestrates_attributes
  attr_accessible :depositinterestrates_attributes
end

class Depositinterestrate < ActiveRecord::Base
belongs_to :depositinterestsetup
#accepts_nested_attributes_for :depositinterestsetup,:allow_destroy => true
attr_accessible :days_from, :days_to, :rate, :senior_increment, :super_senior_increment,    :widow_increment, :id,:depositinterestsetups_attributes
end
```

my view page

```
<h1>Depositinterestsetups#new</h1>
<style>
.alert,.alert_info,.alerth5{
  background-color: rgb(217,237,247);
  /*border-color: rgb(188,232,241);*/
  color: #000;
  /*padding: 8px 20px 8px 14px;*/
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  text-shadow: 0pt 1px 0pt rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
  /*border: 1px solid rgb(251, 238, 213);*/
  border-radius: 4px 4px 4px 4px;
}
body
{
  background-color: #99CCFF;
}
</style>



<%= form_for @depositinterestsetup, :class => "form-horizontal", :html => {:multipart =>    true} do |f| %>  
<% if @depositinterestsetup.errors.any? %>
<ul>
  <% @depositinterestsetup.errors.full_messages.each do |error| %>
    <li><%= error %></li>
  <% end %>
</ul>
<% end %>

<div align = "center"><h1><b> Interest Setup</b></h1></div>
<br/>
<div class='container'>
<div class="alert alert_info", width = "100px">
<table align="center">
  <tr>
    <td>
      <%= f.label :effective_from %>
    </td>
    <td>:</td>
    <td>
      <%= f.text_field :effective_from, :placeholder => 'Effective from' %>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <%= f.label :effective_to %>
    </td>
    <td>:</td>
    <td>
      <%= f.text_field :effective_to, :placeholder => 'Effective to' %>
    </td>
  </tr>
<%= f.fields_for :depositinterestrates, @depositinterestrate do |p| %>

  <%= p.label :days_from %><br />
  <%= p.text_field :days_from %>

<% end %>
  <tr>
    <td clospan= "3" align = "center">
      <%= f.submit "Calculate", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
    </td>
  </tr>

<% end %>
</div>
```

error is "ActiveRecord::UnknownAttributeError in DepositinterestsetupsController#new

```
unknown attribute: depositinterestsetup_id"
```

how to get out of this?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you post your `create action` with related `strong parameters` method?

Comment: Why aren't your variables names in `snake_case`?

Comment: @Pavan: i have edited my controller.check it.

Comment: Post the attributes for `Depositinterestsetup` model.

Comment: @Pavan:I have edited my model page.check it.

Comment: You might be better (and get more answers!) with:  
`class DepositInterestSetupsController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @deposit_interest_setup = DepositInterestSetup.new
    @deposit_interest_rate = @deposit_interest_setup.deposit_interest_rates.build
  end
end`, etc.

Comment: Are you using `Rails 4`?

Comment: Do you have this attribute `depositinterestsetup_id` in in any of your tables?

Comment: @Pavan: I didn't create the depositinterestsetup_id

Comment: @CuriousMind: I'm new to ruby so don't know about snake_case.

Answer (score 0):

As per your model association setup, `Depositinterestsetup` and `Depositinterestrate` have a `1-M Relationship`, i.e.,

*A depositinterestsetup has_many depositinterestrates*

and

*A depositinterestrate belong_to a depositinterestsetup*

In this case you must have a foreign_key setup in `depositinterestrates` table(named `depositinterestsetup_id`) referencing `depositinterestsetups` table's primary key.

You forgot to add this foreign key to the `depositinterestrates` table which is why you receive the error `unknown attribute: depositinterestsetup_id`

To resolve this, you would need to add a field named `depositinterestsetup_id` in `depositinterestrates` table.

```
rails g migration add_depositinterestsetup_id_to_depositinterestrates depositinterestsetup_id:integer:index
```

Run `bundle exec rake db:migrate` after this.

**NOTE:** As @MichaelDurrant suggested in his comment,

you should use `CamelCase` for class names `DepositInterestSetupsController`, `DepositInterestSetup`, `DepositInterestRate` and so on

And

use `snake_case` for corresponding file names like `deposit_interest_setups_controller.rb`, `deposit_interest_setup.rb`, `deposit_interest_rate.rb` and so on.